# Cannot Find Solution For “Membership status cannot be calculated for <dates>” Renewal Error!

Tags: civimember

I have read the related thread and tried many iterations to find a solution for the error

> The membership cannot be saved because the status cannot be calculated for start_date: 20190701 end_date 20200630 join_date 20190701 as at 2019-06-18 07:16:08

I know a lot has been written on this but none of it is working to solve my problem.  I apologize if I am missing something simple.  I am running 5.13.14 in Drupal 7 using PHP 7.2.

I am trying to import members with a contact ID, start date, and membership type ID.  I have tried using an end date as well but that does not help.

Here are my membership rules.

**New**
[image]

**Current**
[image]

**Grace**
[image]

Any help in figuring out what is wrong here is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 2):

The error message shows future start and join dates.  Civi is attempting to the determine the status as of the time of import, but none of the default status rules cover that scenario hence the error message.  'New' only applies from the 'member since' / 'join date' so is not applicable.

One option is to change your join dates to be the current time so that the memberships show as 'New'.  Your memberships would then be regarded as 'current' despite being before the membership start date.

Alternatively, you could create a 'future' status with start event of 'start date' with eg a '-1 month' adjustment, and an end date of 'start date'.  That should let you import the membership which will be inactive until the start date is reached.  (Not tested extensively but seems to work on a quick test.)